# Programmatically accept all cookies in a Windows browser

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, powershell, autohotkey, microsoft-edge

How can I get Windows to confirm / OK all cookies in all sites in a Windows browser?

I don't mind if the language is PowerShell or AutoHotkey or similar, and I don't mind if the browser is Edge or Chrome or Brave or Firefox - I am using the browser inside Windows Sandbox, so I am completely unconcerned about whatever cookies a site presents to me, I want to just accept everything and move on (and anyway, when I close the Windows Sandbox container, everything is deleted anyway).

Comment: You need to enter all your credentials into such program and then make sure it is secure.

Comment: This is easier said than done since each request will be presented differently across different sites.  It's not a part of any standard, any programming framework, or any protocol.  Understand than any solution you come up with will maybe be able to work given some common criteria, but it's highly unlikely you'll be able to do this reliably unless you have a static list of sites you're willing to restrict it to.

Comment: You can use some browser extension like I don't care about cookies

Comment: What's the problem you're actually trying to solve?

Comment: Problem is that I rebuild systems a lot, and I use Windows Sandbox when testing. I go to hundreds of sites in a day, and I really don't care about cookies because I will flush out the browser later. It's a hassle and an annoyance, I just want to accept everything on every site that I go to automatically. Especially as I use Brave Portable, I flush the entire setup every day so all the cookies are gone the next day and then I have to deal with cookie acceptance every day. It's the film Groundhog Day but in real life.